# How to open a Fragment after is opened?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a doubt how to I could open a Fragment after create an object with new.

for example.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment frag = new MyFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag, "MyFrag");
ft.addToBackStack("back");
ft.commit();
```

now, how could I open `MyFragment()` without create other instance ?

I'm trying this, but doesn't works.

```
MyFragment mf = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFrag");
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.show(mf);
```

how could I do this ?

Comment: Store reference in activity?

Comment: use `replace` instead of `show`